# Problem of using natbib with showkeys

Tags: natbib, showkeys

After updating from MacTex 2013 to MacTex 2014 natbib and showkeys stopped working together.

Whenever pdflatex is processing a citation with both packages enabled, I receive the following error

```
./fail.tex:8: TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=5000000].
\rlap #1->\hb@xt@ \z@ {#1\hss }

l.8 Hello world. \cite{jon90}
```

Here is a minimal example

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{showkeys}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

Hello world. \cite{jon90} 

\begin{thebibliography}{1}
 \bibitem[Jones et al.(1990)]{jon90} .....
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Okay after having dealt with this problem for several weeks, I just found that loading showkeys *after* natbib makes the problem go away...

Comment: The problem is that both `showkeys` and `natbib` change the meaning of `\cite`. The addition made by `showkeys` should be performed to the `\cite` command that's used in the document, so after `natbib` has redefined it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There has been a change in `showkeys` from version 3.15 (in TeX Live 2013) and version 3.17 (the current one on TeX Live 2014).

In the older version `showkeys` hooked to the `\cite` command, while now it hooks to `\@citex`, for fixing some issues: here's the annotation in the source file

```
% \changes{v3.17}{2014/04/24}
%         {rededine \cs{@citex} rather than \cs{cite} for tools/4162}
```

The bug it refers to is described [here](http://www.latex-project.org/cgi-bin/ltxbugs2html?category=Tools&responsible=anyone&state=open&keyword=&pr=tools%2F4162&search=)

A consequence of this is that the package must be loaded later than packages redefining `\@citex`, among which there's `natbib`, or the wrong `\@citex` command is redefined, leading to an infinite loop.